# Registration Approval using ASP.NET Identity with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am currently trying to set up a system using ASP.NET and Entity Framework. So far, I have moved a portion of my security/user roles code out of my website, and into my system, which is fine, and seems to be working well. I have two roles, Basically a super user, and another admin role which still has privileges, but not as many. The thing is, I don't want just anyone to be able to register for an account, so anyone who wants an account must be approved first, and then give a role. Is there any way of utilizing ASP.NET Identity with Entity Framework to do such a thing? I am still pretty new to this, I have set up regular accounts but never had a need for approval first. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your attempt to accomplish this, we can help you remove any road blocks you encounter.

Comment: I'm actually struggling finding a function that handles this. I've done some reading about MembershipUser class and utilizing the IsAppoved function within that, but that seems very dated

Comment: allow the users to sign up as normal. use permissions/roles to differentiate 'approved' and 'not approved'